# Flutter - how to change CheckboxListTile size?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

How can I change only the checkbox icon size on a CheckboxListTile?
For a Checkbox widget I was able to change its size using Transform.scale, but on the CheckboxListTile I couldn't manipulate the checkbox icon.
On a tablet screen the size is too small as you can see in the image.

[image: tablet and mobile]

Answer (score 43):

You can use `Transform.scale()`!

It will help you manage the scale of the checkbox.

```dart
            Row(
              children: [
                Transform.scale(
                  scale: 1.3,
                  child: Checkbox(value: mail, onChanged: (value) {}),
                ),
                Text(
                  "Recieve Mail",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                )
              ],
            ),
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if I'm going to help here, but as it looks like you are right on the fact that the CheckBox size cannot be changed when added through a CheckBoxListTile Widget.

Though, you could also create your own tile by inserting a Row for each tile you're using:

```
Row(
 children: [
  Icon(Icons.attach_money),
  Text("Sinal"),
  Transform(
   transform: myTransform, // I don't remember the correct syntax for this one
   child: Checkbox(
    value: true,
    onChanged: (_) {},
   ),
  ),
 ]
),
```

The only thing you'll have to add is to dynamically change the Icon, Text and Checkbox sizes based on the device. (you could use [MediaQuery.of(context).size](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html) in order to achieve this)

Comment: thanks for the answer, inserting a row might solve the size problem, but I don't want to lose the CheckboxListTile functionality, that is clicking anywhere on the tile it checks/unchecks the checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

Could be used the parameter "visualDensity" to change the height and width.

1-Example with default Enums:

```
  CheckboxListTile(
      value: _isChecked,
      title: Text('Example item 1'),
      visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
    ),
```

2-Example with custom values:

```
CheckboxListTile(
    value: _isChecked,
    title: Text('Example item 2'),
    visualDensity: const VisualDensity(horizontal: -4.0, vertical:-4.0),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    width: size.width,
    height: size.height,
    child: Center(
          child: new StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
              return new Transform.scale(
                scale: 1.2,
                child:  Checkbox(
                   value: isChecked,
                    onChanged: (bool? value) {
                      setState(() {
                        isChecked = value!;
                      });
                    },
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),


  );
```

Answer (score 0):

change size of flutter checkbox and colors and round cornder somthing like this:

[image]

```
              Transform.scale(
                scale: 1.2,
                child: Checkbox(
                  value: isBoxChecked,
                  checkColor: Colors.white,
                  activeColor: Colors.green,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(5.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onChanged: (isChecked) {},
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to make some modifications to make some behaviours and constraints better

1. When using Transform.scale(), the text is now slightly shifted.
   Hence the addition of a padding depending on the position of the
   checkbox.
2. GestureDetector allows a wide range of check behaviour
3. Expanded allows to separate the checkbox from the text

```dart
    
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webshop/theme/data/sd_constants.dart';

class MyCheckboxListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Whether this checkbox is checked.
  final bool? value;

  /// Called when the value of the checkbox should change.
  final ValueChanged<bool?>? onChanged;

  /// The primary content of the list tile.
  final Widget? title;

  const MyCheckboxListTile({
    Key? key,
    required this.value,
    required this.onChanged,
    this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => onChanged?.call(value),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
            child: title,
          )),
          Transform.scale(
            scale: 1.5,
            child: Checkbox(
              value: value,
              onChanged: onChanged,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```